# Reason for library not getting linked?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, linker, openssl

I am using **openssl** functions and try to link my program to the **-lssl** and **-lcrypto** libraries using the tricore-gcc from in the [HighTec Developement Platform](https://hightec-rt.com/en/products/development-platform.html) which is based on Eclipse.

Linking using the command:

`OBJ=file1.o file2.o file3.o ....
 tricore-gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(DIR_TO_LIBS) -v -t -o output.elf $(OBJ) -lssl -lcrypto`

outputs the error: `undefined reference to 'ERR_print_errors_fp'`

`DIR_TO_LIBS=-LC:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib which contains the libcrypto.lib libssl.lib`

`LDFLAGS=-Tld/iRAM.ld -Wl,--no-warn-flags -Wl,-n -Wl,--gc-sections`

furthermore, the **-t** flag gives me some further outputs:

```
[some_path]/tricore/bin/ld.exe: mode elf32tricore
[some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161/crti.o
[some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161/crtbegin.o
[some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/crt0-tc27xx.o
file1.o
file2.o
file3.o
/***** some more filesX.o ******/
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_ashldi3.o
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_lshrdi3.o
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)memcpy.o
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)memcmp.o
/***** more files.o ******/
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_ge_df.o
fileX.o: In function 'handleErrors':0
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_lt_df.o
fileX.c:(.text.handleErrors+0xa): error: undefined reference to 'ERR_print_errors_fp'
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_le_df.o
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
([some_path]/lib/gcc/tricore/4.9.4/tc161\libgcc.a)_si_to_df.o
/***** more .o files ******/
```

I see that the libgcc library is included, but my libcrypto and libssl do not appear.

I did test the code using the normal gcc compiler and with the same flags - it worked fine and the libraries appeares when linking with the **-t** flag.

Has anybody an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Did you try [searching SO for that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Derror%3A+undefined+reference+to+%27ERR_print_errors_fp%27)? What's in those macros you didn't post?

Comment: You probably trying to mix your object files built for /tricore/ with OpenSSL libraries built for /Win32/ (likely x86). I guess you have to get correct OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: @jwdonahue, thanks for your answer but I have gone through all posts on stackexchange I have found concerning the error message. I also believe this is a minimal example, by macros do you mean LDFLAGS? -Tld/iRAM.ld -Wl,--no-warn-flags -Wl,-n -Wl,--gc-sections

Comment: @Yann Doneaud, thank you for the hint but I am afraid there are no special openssl libraries compiled for tricore usage

Comment: So you have to cross compile them yourself

Comment: that could be it, thanks!

Comment: @jonnyx, I agree, it was a minimal (M), but not complete (C) example. [Edit] your post to include those macro definitions.